# stop capture data with libpcap and save it in a file

Tags: c++, c, libpcap

I'm working with libpcap with c++. I want to save the capture to a file, and I use this:

```
  if ((pcount = pcap_loop (p, -1, &pcap_dump, (char *) pd)) < 0)
    {
      pcap_perror (p, prestr);
   }
```

how I can stop the capture and save data when I want?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to your question: how to stop, and how to save. Let's handle each in turn.

1. How to "stop" the capture

   In short: you don't "stop" the capture - you capture a limited amount, and check if that's enough.

   The [`pcap` documentation](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) indicates that the second argument is the number of packets to capture. By specifying `-1`, you're telling the system to capture until error.

   If you're going to be checking for some other condition (say, a variable set by some other part of your system), perhaps `pcap_loop` with an argument of `-1` isn't appropriate. The other options in the `pcap` docs look more appropriate:

   - `pcap_next` will just grab the next packet, so you can check after every packet, OR
   - `pcap_dispatch` will process a batch of packets

   Given that you're trying to save output, `pcap_dispatch` is probably the better choice.  So something like:

   ```
   while (something_tells_me_to_keep_going) {
       // process one buffer-full (error handling removed for brevity)
       pcap_dispatch(p, -1, &pcap_dump, (char*) pd);
       // possibly update something_tells_me_to_keep_going, based on time or whatever
   }
   ```
2. How to save the data

   You've specified the callback handler `pcap_dump`, which is designed to dump packet data to a file that previously opened with `pcap_dump_open`. So presumably, you have (or will need) something like this before your call to `pcap_loop` (or `pcap_dispatch`):

   ```
       pcap_dumper_t *pd = pcap_dump_open(p, "my_save_file.pcap");
   ```

   ... where `p` was the `pcap_t*` stream you created with `pcap_open_live`, etc.

   (See [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/3869) note from libcap author clarifying use of this function).

   Finally, when you're done, close the file with:

   ```
   pcap_dump_close(pd);
   ```

References:

- http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/3869
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_dump_open/
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_loop/